# Httpclient multipart/form-data pust image

Tags: c#, .net, multipartform-data

I am trying to send a Put request with binary file to upload to the server, using Httpclient.SendAsync or Httpclient.PutAsync. But all i got is 400 bad request in server response. Here is the code

```
private static HttpResponseMessage Upload()
    {
        var apiUri = string.Format(url);
        string url = (url);

        var message = new HttpRequestMessage();
        message.RequestUri = new Uri(apiUri);
        message.Method = HttpMethod.Put;

        var fileObj = Images.ChooseImageAndToInfoObject();

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            var filestream = new FileStream(fileObj.filePath, FileMode.Open);

            content.Add(new StreamContent(filestream), fileObj.fileName, fileObj.fileNameWithExtension);
            content.Add(new StringContent("file"), "withName");
            content.Add(new StringContent("string"), "fileName");
            content.Add(new StringContent("image/*"), "mimeType");

            message.Content = content;

            message.Headers.Add("Authorization", MyToken);


            // var res = client.SendAsync(message).Result;
             var response = client.PutAsync(url, content).Result;
            return response;
        }
```

Hope for you, guys

Comment: Probably not the acute problem, but: `using (var client = new HttpClient())` - [you are using HttpClient wrong](https://josef.codes/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it necessary to send the filename and mimetype via multipart-formdata? If not try to send the data as StreamContent and set the filename and mime type via the content header:

```
private static HttpResponseMessage Upload()
    {
        var apiUri = string.Format(url);
        string url = (url);

        var message = new HttpRequestMessage();
        message.RequestUri = new Uri(apiUri);
        message.Method = HttpMethod.Put;

        var fileObj = Images.ChooseImageAndToInfoObject();

        using (var client = new HttpClient())

        var filestream = new FileStream(fileObj.filePath, FileMode.Open);

        var content = new StreamContent(filestream);
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileObj.filePath));
        content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data") 
        { 
            Name = "\"files\"", 
            FileName = "\"" + fileName + "\""
        };

        message.Content = content;

        message.Headers.Add("Authorization", MyToken);


        // var res = client.SendAsync(message).Result;
        var response = client.PutAsync(url, content).Result;
        return response;
```

Send the content via PUT if you set the file to a specific id or via Post:

```
var response = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;
```

Comment: What kind of library (or NuGet) are u using for MimeMapping? MymeTypes 2.0.2 NuGet is not available for my version of .Net Framework wich is lower than 4.7.2

Comment: * wich is 4.7.2

Comment: MimeMappping is part of System.Web since version 4.5:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.web.mimemapping?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Alternatively you can replace MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileObj.filePath) by any other string, if you get the mime type from somewhere else.